# Why were the entire HTTP APIs in Android deprecated in API level 22?

Tags: android, apache, http, deprecated

Now that the entire `org.apache.http` APIs are deprecated, it seems like that I should be using `java.net` API instead.

Hasn't it become more complicated to code?

Comment: *Why were the entire HTTP APIs in Android deprecated in API level 22?* <= use google, asked bazillion times here and also easy to find ... *Hasn't it become more complicated to code?* => primarily opinion-based  ... where is the real question then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why were the entire HTTP APIs in Android deprecated in API level 22?

Google had announced a couple of years earlier that they were no longer maintaining their edition of Apache's HttpClient. Android 5.1's deprecation and Android M's removal of HttpClient simply reinforces this.

> Hasn't it become more complicated to code?

You are welcome to
 consider switching to
[OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) and their HttpClient
compatibility layer, or consider switching to
[Apache's separate Android edition of HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html).
Otherwise, consider OkHttp's native API. Or, use dedicated
APIs for things like REST-style Web services (e.g., Retrofit) or image loading
(e.g., Picasso, Universal Image Loader). Any of those would be viable alternatives to `HttpUrlConnection`, if you do not like that API.

Answer (score 0):

- Which client is best?

-> Apache HTTP client has fewer bugs on Eclair and Froyo. It is the best choice for these releases.

-> For Gingerbread and better, **`HttpURLConnection is the best choice.`** Its simple API and small size makes it great fit for Android. Transparent compression and response caching reduce network use, improve speed and save battery. New applications should use HttpURLConnection; it is where we will be spending our energy going forward.

Please visit this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) for details.

Comment: From starting version of android this apache http clients have issues. But they are best at that time so they are not deprecated. And later they continued to go on. But now from api version 22, they finally deprecated it.

Comment: see this. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html

Comment: let me highlight that in my answer.